# How to transpose unique entries in a column and print values from another column

Tags: python, awk

I have a file input.txt with two columns, I want to split the second column by ";" and transpose the unique entries then count and list how many matches are in column 1.

**This is my tab-delimited input.txt file**

```
Gene     Biological_Process
BALF2   metabolic process
CHD4    cell organization and biogenesis;metabolic process;regulation of biological process
TCOF1   cell organization and biogenesis;regulation of biological process;transport
TOP1    cell death;cell division;cell organization and biogenesis;metabolic process;regulation of biological process;response to stimulus
BcLF1   0
BALF5   metabolic process
MTA2    cell organization and biogenesis;metabolic process;regulation of biological process
MSH6    cell organization and biogenesis;metabolic process;regulation of biological process;response to stimulus
```

**my expected output1**

```
Biological_Process  Gene
metabolic process   BALF2   CHD4    TOP1    BALF5   MTA2    MSH6
cell organization and biogenesis    CHD4    TCOF1   TOP1    MTA2    MSH6
regulation of biological process    CHD4    TCOF1   TOP1    MTA2    MSH6
transport   TCOF1
cell death  TOP1
cell division   TOP1
response to stimulus    TOP1    MSH6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat script.awk 
#! /usr/bin/awk -f 

BEGIN {
    FS = "[\t;]";  # sep can be a regex
    OFS = "\t"
}

NR>1 && /^[A-Z]/{  # skip header & blank lines 
    for(i=NF; i>1; i--)
        if($i)   # skip empty bio-proc
           a[$i] = a[$i] OFS $1 
}
END{
    print "Biological_Process","Gene(s)"
    for(x in a)
        print x a[x] 
}

$ ./script.awk input.dat 
Biological_Process  Gene(s)
cell death  TOP1
regulation of biological process    CHD4    TCOF1   TOP1    MTA2    MSH6
transport   TCOF1
cell division   TOP1
metabolic process   BALF2   CHD4    TOP1    BALF5   MTA2    MSH6
response to stimulus    TOP1    MSH6
cell organization and biogenesis    CHD4    TCOF1   TOP1    MTA2    MSH6
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse all the data first, e.g. start with a blank dictionary and then read each line of your file (skip line 0 if it's a header) `open your file ... iterate over each line`, for every entry in columns > 0 create a dictionary key for that string with its value as the string from column = 0 using string methods like `split` and `strip` and `dict[gene...] = process...`. Then print/write out each `.items` from the dict:

input.txt

```
gene process
A cell org bio
B cell bio
C 0
D org
```

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():

    pros = {}

    with open("input.txt", "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            cols = line.strip().split()
            if len(cols) >= 1:
                for pro in cols[1:]:
                    if pro not in pros:
                        pros[pro] = []
                    pros[pro] += [cols[0]]

    with open("output.txt", "w") as ofile:
        for key,val in pros.items():
            ofile.writelines(f'{key}\t' + '\t'.join(val) + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

run

```
$ chmod +x ./script.py
$ ./script.py
$ cat ./output.txt
```

output.txt

```
process gene
cell    A       B
org     A       D
bio     A       B
0       C
```

Comment: I will appreciate if you can help with it

Comment: @Ibk updated answer, should give you 95% of what you need

Comment: Thank you @MrMattBusby. I got this error
 File "./transpose_column.py", line 18
    ofile.writelines(f'{key}\t' + '\t'.join(val) + '\n')
                              ^

Comment: Sorry that's not enough information without the trace. Try some debugging like just writing a blank string? Maybe you're using an older Python than me (3.9) and cannot use that string format `f'...'`. Or instead of writing out to ofile, just `print(pros)` to check things are working. If you could accept my answer though I'm trying to grab a few points to enable more SO features ;)

Comment: I use recent Python and got it to run but it did not give the desired output. Please Note that all entries under the second column (Biological_Process) are to be separated or split by the semicolon so you can get a unique list of the different Biological_Processes in column, this will form our new column 1 and genes that have such Biological_Process will be listed in front of each Biological_Process. You can use the input file I presented to test the script. Thank you

Comment: We're off topic now @Ibk and really -- why would you ask for a Python coding answer if you don't do Python coding and have no intention of participating? My template, which I was nice enough to spend 30min along with the answer, gets you now 99% the way there and answers your question of "How", it was only your comment that you asked for a fully-coded solution. You can make the last yard.