# Processing a multiset to a set of lists

Tags: bash, awk

In a plain text file,

```
bag1: apple
bag3: pear
bag2: potato
bag2: orange
bag1: banana
bag2: banana
onion
```

needs to be converted to

```
bag1: [apple, banana]
bag2: [banana, orange, potato]
bag3: [pear]
non-categorized: onion
```

Of course, `sort` is the first step, then using python to check go over one by one. But is there a shell script alternative?

Comment: see: transpose and regroup from a couple of days ago  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369833

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: is there a requirement to store the result for later use, or do you just need to print to stdout?

Comment: Just print with basic text concat.

Comment: To get started with the topic: `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2} END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file`

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus `$2` is empty for the `onion` line

Comment: Because you also have to care about the non-categorized items, I would not care about sorting; just loop over all the lines and collect on the way all the items for each set. In the end, loop again, but now over you sets, and print the result. BTW, while it is not impossible to do it in plain bash, it will cause you much less headache if you write the whole program in awk (or Python, or Ruby, or Perl, or Java, or virtually any other language).

Answer (score 2):

Are standard tools OK? If so then you can use `sort` and `awk`:

```bash
sort file.txt |
awk '
    {
        if (idx = index($0,": ")) {
            key = substr($0,1,idx)
            val = substr($0,idx+2)
        } else {
            key = "non-categorized:"
            val = $0
        }
        arr[key] = ((key in arr) ? arr[key] ", " : "") val
    }
    END {
        for (key in arr)
            print key, "[", arr[key], "]"
    }
'
```

```
non-categorized: [ onion ]
bag1: [ apple, banana ]
bag2: [ banana, orange, potato ]
bag3: [ pear ]
```

**remark:** while the values in brackets are guaranteed to be alphabetically ordered because of the `sort` command, the categories in the final output are not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`:

```
awk -F ":[[:space:]]+" '
{   key=NF>1 ? $1 : "non-categorized"
    value=NF>1 ? $2 : $1
    set[key]=set[key] ? set[key] ", " value : value
}
END {
    for (k in set) {
        print k ": [" set[k] "]"
    }
}
' file | sort
```

Prints:

```
bag1: [apple, banana]
bag2: [potato, orange, banana]
bag3: [pear]
non-categorized: [onion]
```